# Is there a way to update a SQLAlchemy object at once?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I am using SQLAlchemy for my first fullstack project.

Backend is built with FastAPI and mySQL while using SQLAlchemy and Pydantic.

I was able to get an object made with contents from different tables with a simple function.

My question is that is there a way to apply the changes made to the object in a simple way?

example:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "MM",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "types": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "desc": "it is description"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "desc": "2nd desc"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Got the object above from 3 different tables, user table, item table, and type table.
followed a tutorial https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#crud-utils

after making some modification in front-end the object became

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "MM",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "types": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "desc": "1st desc changed"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "not assigned yet since it's only on front-end",
          "types": [
            {
              "id": 3,
              "desc": "3rd desc"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I need to add a column in `item table` for the newly added item, update `desc` for item_id in `item table` and delete column with `type_id` 2 in `type table`

Do I need to check for all the change and query all the difference by myself? or is there a way that can do all those for me?

The example is just for you to understand.